# How to use TinyMCE in Angular2

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have a Java Web Application (using Spring) with a GUI based on JSP using a local instance of TinyMCE. Now I want to replace the JSP with Angular.

Here is what I got:
My index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Client</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../editor/tinymce.full.min.js"></script> <!-- Path to local instance of TinyMCE -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I installed the TinyMCE package like this:

```
 $ npm install --save @tinymce/tinymce-angular
```

and added the EditorModule from @tinymce/tinymce-angular in my app.module.ts. In one of my component's html file I use this line:

```
<editor id="editedCorporateAction" [init]="initData">{{ editor.editor_content }}</editor>
```

I define initData in the affiliated TypeScript file in ngOnInit():

```
this.initData = {
      init_instance_callback: (editor) => {
        ///
      },
      selector : '#editedCorporateAction',
      content_css : this.editor.content_css,
      skin_url : this.editor.skin_url,
      height : '100%',
      object_resizing : false,
      element_format : 'xhtml',
      language : this.getEditorLanguage(this.editor.locale_language),
      plugins : this.getPlugins(),
      statusbar : false,
      menubar : false,
      browser_spellcheck : !/\bEdge\/14\b/.test(navigator.userAgent), /* Spell checking works very badly in Edge 14! */
      toolbar : this.getToolbarConfig(),
      define_text_template_url : this.editor.define_text_template_url,
      list_text_template_categories_and_todogroups_url : this.editor.list_text_template_categories_and_todogroups_url,
      search_todo_group_url : this.editor.search_todo_group_url,
      /// and more
};
```

Now the page loads without any errors or exceptions, however the editor is not initialized.
What am I doing wrong? I did a lot of googling but I only found tutorials for projects using TinyCloud.

Edit: I am using TinyMCE Version 4.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is because you use the content inside the element however it need's to be passed to the initValue property.
Also maybe some of your initPropertys are false. I've made you a [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jolqrz) with an working solution of tinymce which also shows how to get the output of the component:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jolqrz